# Print Gantt View

Tags: javascript, visual-web-part

We need develop a custom webpart to print the Gantt view of a tasks list.

Has someone developed some similar? We are trying to do it with the jsgrid library in JavaScript, using the LaunchPrintPreview function, but we cannot get the tasks bar image with this method. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It is not easy. At the time, I researched several options and chose the following:

Create a SharePoint **page Layout** with C # to read the contents of a list and displayed in the format required by **Google Chart API**.

While Google has a view **Time Line** and other **Gantt**, I chose the first. I wrote down the links:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline

At that time I made integration with Project Server, but can do with SharePoint. I'll show you an example of how it turned out:

[image: Sample]

Fuente: http://www.pampapoint.com/integracion-project-server-google/